# Does the stock market usually overshoot both ways?

Tags: stock-market

I've loosened Lee Spelman's contention from "always" to "usually". [I pasted her biography](https://am.jpmorgan.com/gb/en/asset-management/gim/adv/profiles/u/lee-spelman) to prove she appears qualified.

> Lee Spelman, managing director, is the Head of U.S. Equity. She led the Client Portfolio Management from 2003 until 2016. An employee since 1989, Lee was previously a senior research analyst in the U.S. Equity Research group with responsibility for the technology sector. She was also the global technology sector team leader. Lee holds a B.S. in economics from the Wharton School of Business at the University of Pennsylvania and is a CFA charterholder. She is a trustee of the University of Pennsylvania. She holds Series 7, 24 and 63 licenses and is a member of The New York Society of Security Analysts.

[US stocks erase all losses for the year | Financial Times](https://www.ft.com/content/1dfaeb58-6d65-4f17-b710-b1ebc6622649)

> US stocks have climbed more than 40 per cent from a mid-March low, with the Nasdaq up 10.6 per cent since the start of the year and the S&P 500 now little changed. The rebound has come in spite of the recession caused by the coronavirus pandemic and civil unrest in the US after the killing of George Floyd.
>
> **“The history of markets is that they always overshoot both ways,”** said Lee Spelman, head of US equities for JPMorgan Asset Management. “What you’re seeing is an expectation of a V-shaped recovery and that may prove to be too optimistic.”
>
> Stanley Druckenmiller, a former hedge fund manager, said that “the excitement of reopening is allowing a lot of these companies that have been casualties of Covid to come back and come back in force”.
>
> Support by the US Federal Reserve has also helped to alleviate the economic strain. The central bank has [slashed](https://www.ft.com/content/a9a28bc0-66fb-11ea-a3c9-1fe6fedcca75) interest rates to zero, [launched](https://www.ft.com/content/b71f0c32-6cfb-11ea-89df-41bea055720b) an unlimited bond-buying programme and announced [11 lending facilities](https://www.ft.com/content/a1fba7cd-5329-46e6-82a8-57149e409f6c).
>
> “I would also say I underestimated how many red lines, and how far, the Fed would go,” Mr Druckenmiller said, in an interview with CNBC.

Comment: Too vague a question. Define “overshoot.”

Comment: What would it mean for a market to *not* overshoot? The price goes up or down and then just... stays there and never changes again?